# Question mark at the end of the output

Tags: c

Trying to implement `detab` function which is described in K&R book http://clc-wiki.net/wiki/K%26R2_solutions:Chapter_1:Exercise_20 an faced a problem: when outputting a replaced string there's a question mark in the end of the output. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 9999

void get_text(char output[]);
void detab(char input[], char output[], int tab_size);

int main()
{
    char input[MAXLINE];
    char final[MAXLINE];
    get_text(input);
    detab(input, final, 4);
    for (int i = 0; final[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        putchar(final[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}

void get_text(char output[])
{
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE && (c = getchar()) != EOF; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = c;
    }
    output[i + 1] = '\0';
}

void detab(char input[], char output[], int tab_size)
{
    int c = 0;
    int r = 0;
    for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        c = input[i];
        if(c == '\t')
        {
            for (int t = 0; t < tab_size; ++t)
            {
                output[r] = '.';
                r++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            output[r] = c;
            r++;
        }
    }
    output[r] = '\0';
}
```

And here is the output when I'm passing the file with following content 'asdasdads  tasdasdasdasdasd    sadasdasd':
`asdasdads....tasdasdasdasdasd....sadasdasd?` (? at the end).
Why there is a question mark at the end?

Comment: I'm suspicious of output[i + 1] = '\0';

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a specific reason not to use such stdio functions as `gets` or `printf`?

Comment: @kuroi neko, or is there any reason to write those functions in C while there are python or ruby? :)

Comment: +1 for not using `gets`. @kuroineko; Why are you suggesting him to use [`gets`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21068539/2455888)?

Comment: @haccks Just for the vintage feel of good ole K&R exercises :). But you're right, it was not a really smart move to advise a new fellow C programmer to use something that has long been deprecated for very good reasons.

Comment: I seem this is so does not take into account the tab stop position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
output[i + 1] = '\0';
```

You don't need to add `1` here, it was already done in the loop. (First `i` is incremented and then `i < MAXLINE && (c = getchar()) != EOF` is tested, so `i` is one higher than in the last loop iteration already)

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess that's in place of an unprintable character. The characters in `final` aren't initialized to anything in particular, and you're leaving a gap at the end of the detabbed string when you say:

```
output[i + 1] = '\0';
```

`output[i]`, one past the output text, is still uninitialized.

You want:

```
output[i] = '\0';
```